# remove edge flickering in css tab

Tags: asp.net, css

[image][image]
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bxhs.jpg): http://i.stenter code [image: hereack.imgur.com/emPdr.jpg]
i want to remove left side of user group tab sharp sized border. i want to remove that small gap of white in left side of user group tab
This is the css applied for selected tab.

```
ul.tabs li.selected a {-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;-moz-border-left-colors: none;   -moz-border-right-colors: none;    -moz-border-top-colors: none;   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;    border-color: #B7B7B7 #B7B7B7 White;    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;    border-width: 1px;    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;    top: 0;}
ul.tabs li a {-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;    -moz-border-top-colors: none;    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D8DAE2;    border-color: #CCCCCC #CCCCCC #B7B7B7;    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;    border-width: 1px;    color: Black;    font: 11px verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;enter code here    outline: medium none;    padding: 5px 16px;
    position: relative;    text-decoration: none;    z-index: 1;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a change to your css:-

```
ul.tabs li.selected a {
    top:1px; //change
}
```

Comment: yes i got it thank u: i changes css asul.tabs li.selected a {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border-color: #B7B7B7 #B7B7B7 White;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px; border-bottom-style:none;
}

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery ui, the margin right is on the li element, not on a.

So your code should look like:

```
ul.tabs li { margin-right:0 }
```

if still not working, add

```
 ul.tabs li  { margin-right:0 !Important; }
```